# What are valid values for CSS Property "padding-right-ltr-source"?

Tags: css, firefox, padding

I am trying to solve a box padding problem in Firefox. When I expanded the "padding" property of the affected span element, I saw there is a property called "padding-right-ltr-source" with value "physical":

```
>padding: 0px 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right-value: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left-value: 15px;
    padding-left-ltr-source: physical;
    padding-left-rtl-source: physical;
    padding-right-ltr-source: physical;
    padding-right-rtl-source: physical;
```

What are the other possible values for these properties?

EDIT:
I ended up using transparent border instead of padding, since it has consistant behaviour across the browsers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961741/css-expanded-shorthand-properties-what-is-border-left-color-ltr-sourcephysi

Comment: the only other value i know for this is `logical`, but i dont think youll find much documentation on this.

Comment: This thread is helpful as well: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?649256-what-is-the-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property has two possible values: "physical" and "logical".  It's also an internal property that you can't set directly in a stylesheet.  It's used to implement the interactions of things like a stylesheet setting both `padding-start` and `padding-right` in a single rule, on elements with different directionalities...  The former sets `padding-left-ltr-source: logical` and `padding-right-rtl-source: logical` while the latter sets `padding-right-ltr-source: physical` and `padding-right-rtl-source: physical`.