# Should we use compact css like 'border' or expand it like 'border-color', 'border-width'?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I can write the style for a border like this :

```
border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
```

or like this :

```
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-bottom-color: #dddddd;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-image-outset: 0 0 0 0;
border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
border-image-slice: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1 1 1 1;
border-left-color-ltr-source: physical;
border-left-color-rtl-source: physical;
border-left-color-value: #dddddd;
border-left-style-ltr-source: physical;
border-left-style-rtl-source: physical;
border-left-style-value: solid;
border-left-width-ltr-source: physical;
border-left-width-rtl-source: physical;
border-left-width-value: 2px;
border-right-color-ltr-source: physical;
border-right-color-rtl-source: physical;
border-right-color-value: #dddddd;
border-right-style-ltr-source: physical;
border-right-style-rtl-source: physical;
border-right-style-value: solid;
border-right-width-ltr-source: physical;
border-right-width-rtl-source: physical;
border-right-width-value: 2px;
border-top-color: #dddddd;
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
```

*What is the best preferred method?* The reason Im asking this is that when I use Firebug, it always expand these rules like the one I showed below.

Also if you know please tell me how to turn this off in firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Firebug expands it is so you can see how the browser *computes* the styles as specified by the shorthand. You can use longhand properties if you want to avoid cascading conflicts such as a shorthand overriding a longhand, but you need to research which properties are applicable and which are not.

The vast majority of the values in your example are implementation-specific and therefore foreign to other browsers. The `border` shorthand property only corresponds to a few specific longhands in the CSS standard, such as `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`, as well as any of the sides (and width/style/color for *each* individual side). Some standard longhands that belong to their own shorthands (or not at all) include `border-top-left-radius`, which is not actually shown in your input CSS. The rest (`*-ltr/rtl-source`) [are for internal use only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166787/what-are-valid-values-for-css-property-padding-right-ltr-source/21171072#21171072).

Comment: Can we prevent firebug from expanding like that?

Comment: @EApubs: I use the built-in developer tools but I'm sure Firebug will let you filter the properties using search.